# is there any way to solve the following case with out using maps

Tags: apex, trigger

Create Custom field called “Number of Locations” (Its API Name: NumberofLocations__c) on the Account Object (Data Type=Number)
The following trigger creates the number of contacts which are equal to the number which we will enter in the Number of Locations field on the Account Object

```
trigger ContactsCreation on Account (after insert) {
    list<contact> listContact = new list<contact>();
    map<id,decimal> mapAcc=new map<id,decimal>();

    for(Account acc:trigger.new){
        mapAcc.put(acc.id,acc.NumberofLocations__c);
    }

    if(mapAcc.size()>0 && mapAcc!=null){
        for(Id accId:mapAcc.keyset()){
            for(integer i=0;i<mapAcc.get(accId);i++){
                contact newContact=new contact();
                newContact.accountid=accId;
                newContact.lastname='contact'+i;
                listContact.add(newContact);
            }
        }
    }

    if(listContact.size()>0 && listContact!=null)
        insert listContact;
}
```

Comment: Wow I don't think this code would compile.

Comment: There is no need to use a Map in this situation. In fact, the Map strikes me as a much less natural idiom than a simple `for` loop. It's also implemented incorrectly and will not do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Like @MartinLezer said, this code will not compile as you have an out-of-scope reference to `acc`.

Comment: There's a lot of problem with this code. You should probably try to get some badges on Trailhead before trying to write triggers.

Comment: Please don't replace your question content with completely different code. You are welcome to answer your own question if you've discovered the solution.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding some extra newlines to your code to make it easier to digest. Feel free to undo those changes if you think they're detrimental. A quick tip: To format a block of text as code here, each line needs to have at least 4 blank spaces at the start of the line. The easiest way to format your code here is to copy/paste, then highlight your code and press `ctrl` + `k` (or `cmd` + `k` on Mac)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome Harsha,

The map is not needed, you could try something like this

```
trigger AccountLocations on Account (after insert) {
    //create contacts as per the number provided in AccountLocations_C field on Account Object//

    list<contact> contacts = new list<contact>();
    for(Account acc : Trigger.new){
        if (acc.NumberLocations__c > 0) {
            contacts.add(new Contact(c.AccountId = acc.id;
                        c.LastName = 'contact'+i;));
        }
    }

    if (!contacts.isEmpty() && contacts.size() > 0) {
        insert contacts;
    } 

}
```